# Adjective describing possession by someone else

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, possessives, negation

Is there any adjective in English that would describe a quality of belonging or being in the possession of someone else who is not the speaker?

In short, what adjective would you substitute for the words in bold below:

> What's inside of this bag?
>
> I don't know. This is **not my** bag.

or

> What's inside of this bag?
>
> I don't know. This bag is **not mine**.

or

> Jack, don't touch that toy car.
>
> Why?
>
> Because that toy is **not yours**.

Comment: To keep this consistent (and correct), the third example would be "that toy is **not yours**."

Comment: @sq33G - All right. Changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd probably use **somebody else's**.

Comment: that's not a good answer. "sb else's"? What does that mean? Is it even English?

Comment: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/sb?q=sb

Comment: Well, it's still not something I would recommend anyone use except in the most informal of circumstances, and certainly not in speech.

Comment: Since it's the correct answer, once you expand the silly abbreviation, I've edited it rather than add my own answer.

Answer (score 3):

*another's*

But notice that *another's* is not an adjective.  I'm pretty sure that the kind of word you're describing cannot be an adjective.

Comment: how about simply other's?

Comment: "other's" doesn't seem to fit in the example sentences above.

Answer (score 0):

There are analogous words in other languages with the meaning sought in the OP. However, bilingual dictionaries do not show a unique equivalent word in English for them.